# Continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that the set { $ x \in \mathbb R : f(x)<0$ } is singleton

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am in desperate need of an example of a continuous function (if exists) $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that

$ f(x) <0 $ for exactly one $x \in \mathbb R $ ; please help .

Comment: You're gonna have a hard time finding it.

Comment: If $x_0$ is a point where $f(x_0) <0$, try to argue with continuity that there is an open nbd of $x_0$, where $f(x)<0$. So, it can't be singleton.

Answer (score 3):

Your set is the preimage of an open set $(-\infty,0)$, so it has to be open, because $f$ is continuous. But singletons are clearly not open, so your function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. Because when it $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0$ which for $f(x_0)<0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})=f(x_0)<0$. So there exists a $N_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq N_0,\ \frac{f(x_0)}{2}<f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})-f(x_0)<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$. Hence for every $n\geq N_0,\ f(x_0+\frac{1}{n})<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}<0$. That means $f$ at least in countable infinite points is negative. That points are elements of the set  $\{x_0+\frac{1}{n}|\ n\geq N_0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody wrote it so far explicitly (though proofs are given): Such a function can't exist due to the intermediate value theorem. Let $f(x_0)<0$ and wlog $x_0<y$ such that $f(y)\geq 0$ then there is a $\xi\in(x_0,y)$ such that $f(\xi)<\min\{0,\frac{f(y)+f(x_0)}{2}\}$ and thus negative

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not exist. if $f(x)<0$, because it is continuous on point $x$, then there must exist $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(z)<0 , \forall z\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$

Answer (score 0):

Your function cannot exist. Suppose that at a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $f(x_0)<0$. Then as $f$ is continuous there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$ 
x \in (x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta) \implies |f(x_0) - f(x)| <\frac{f(x_0)}{2}
$$
so that $f(x) \in (f(x_0) -\frac{f(x_0)}{2}, f(x_0) + \frac{f(x_0)}{2})$. As $f(x_0) + \frac{f(x_0)}{2} < 0$ we must have $f(x)<0$ for each $x \in (x_0 - \delta,x_0 + \delta)$. So $x_0$ cannot be the only point.